# Django view: get_context_data() vs get()

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

We can do this in Django:

```
class LoginView(generic.FormView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        common = CommonView(self, **kwargs)
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['common'] = common.infos
```

or:

```
class LoginView(generic.FormView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        common = CommonView(self, **kwargs)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'common': common.infos })
```

Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `get_context_data()` is interesting since it has only one goal (do one thing and do it well): pass data to the template.

On the other hand, `get()` has many tasks to do in order to return an `HttpResponse` in the end. `get()` should rather be a skeleton of method calls, delegating tasks. Among them, you have `get_context_data()`, and others according to the class you are inheriting.

As long as it is possible, I think it is better to let the parent class(es) handle the `get()`, `post()`, ... methods and use the convenience methods they provide.

As far as I'm concerned, the only case for which I had to handle the `get()` method myself is when writing generic views.

Answer (score 2):

None of them is "better". I'd say it depends on the scenario what you need to do. `get_context_data()` is called for all the request methods (`post`, `get`), so if you need to have there some data available every time, use `get_context_data()`. If you need the data only for a specific request method (eg. in `get`), then put it in `get`.